# Getting Dependency Issues and How to Create a Logger File for Specific Classes in AEM?

Tags: java, aem

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMx3z.png)I'm currently facing difficulties adding logger files for a specific Java class in AEM, and I'm unable to obtain the logger object due to missing dependencies. I'm uncertain about the appropriate steps to resolve this within the AEM environment. Can you guide me on how to correctly configure the logger for a specific class, considering the issue with missing logger object dependency?

Comment: Are you configuring via /system/console/slinglog or via configuration file to be deployed via code? Can you share an screenshot and/or stack trace of the error you are facing and what you have tried?

Comment: Thanks for responding. I've included the image link in the description, but it seems there's a dependency missing. Could you please guide me on how to create Logger files for a specific Java class via /system/console/slinglog?

Comment: First you will need to solve the dependency issue, otherwise, the bundle will not even start. Please update your pom.xml to include any external dependencies, and of course, make sure you are importing the expected classes in the Java file. After that, go to /system/console/bundles and make sure the bundle is active. Then, in /system/console/slinglog just add the log name, the package, and click save. There are examples right there of the default loggers that AEM brings out of the box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the following steps

##### 1. Check if the required dependencies are included in your Maven pom.xml file. If any dependencies are missing, you can add them to ensure the proper functioning of your project.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>{slf4j-version}</version> 
</dependency>
```

##### 2. Import the package

`import org.slf4j.Logger;`

##### 3. Provide proper syntax for logger object creation

`private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(YourClass.class);`

##### 4. Access the LogSupport page in your web console by navigating to `http://localhost:4502/system/console/slinglog`.

- Click on the "Add new logger" button to create a new logging configuration.
- Specify the desired log levels (such as Info, Debug, etc.) in the Logger Levels section according to your requirements.
- Decide on the "Additive" setting based on whether you want the new logger's configuration to be combined with (true) or completely override (false) its parent logger's configuration.
- Optionally, define a custom log file path (e.g., logs/customName.log) in the Logger File section, or keep the default file.
- In the Logger section, provide either a class path from your application's classes or a package path to configure logging at the class or package level, respectively.

You can directly inspect the log files in the crx-quickstart/logs directory to view all the logger files present. You can use a text editor or command-line tools to access these logs. Once you locate your logger's created file, you can open it to view the logger messages.